# Page visit tracking in Angular single page application using sitecore (Beascon.js)

Tags: angular, sitecore, beacon

I need to track all page visit in Angular single page application using sitecore (Beacon.js)
So I have added this line  in inxex.html and it is logging the page visit only once but not every component visit.
Can someone please help me to achieve this. Thanks...!

I think i have to write some code in AppComponent so it can capture every router event change.... but not sure how to invoke the beacon.js function call here....

Answer (score 0):

Put a canActivateService on each router path like this.

```
    {
        path: "dialog",
        component: DialogComponent,
        canActivate: [canActivateService]
    }
```

Here's the service:

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate } from "@angular/router";
import { RestangularService } from "./restangular.service";
import { EventService } from "./event.service";

@Injectable({
   providedIn: "root"
})
export class canActivateService implements CanActivate { 

constructor(private rs: RestangularService, private es: EventService) {}
   // returns a true or false promise
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      // all inbound route information is contained in the two params above
      // which can be logged, even asynchronously
      // return true or false here.
   }
}
```

Note that there are about five other "hookable" events. canActivate is just one of them.